# How to pass a variable containing space in bash as a loop argument?

Tags: bash

good day,
I am creating a script to read one level of subfolders/directories of a path. The script is like so:

```
#loopdir.sh
for i in `ls -d $1`
do
echo $i
done
```

But when I tried to use it to read /media/My\ Passport/, it reads the argument as two different dirs:

```
$ ./loopdir.sh /media/My\ Passport/
ls: cannot access /media/My: No such file or directory
Passport/
```

Comment: other ref: http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/314/how-to-list-just-directories-the-correct-way/

Comment: Thank you @kepinpin for un-accepting my wrong answer. Now, I can delete it... :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this instead (my understanding is that you want to list subdirs, Am I right?) :

```
for i in "$1"/*; do
    echo "${i%/}"
done
```

Parsing `ls` output is a **bad idea** : it's is a tool for interactively looking at file information. Its output is formatted for humans and will cause bugs in scripts. Use globs or find instead. Understand why: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

And (last but not least) :  **USE MORE QUOTES!** They are vital. Also, learn the difference between ' and " and `. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: I want to second this consideration of parsing ls. It is widely known for containing black magic that can break what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround your `$i` with quotes: `echo "$i"`

Comment: sorry, I've just tried it, no dice. The output is still:
    ls: cannot access /media/My: No such file or directory
    Passport/

Comment: Why the backslash in your filename?

Comment: This is going to bother me all night.

Comment: There is no backslash in filename. It has been added by bash, to escape space between My & Passport.

Comment: Quoting won't help, as there's nothing that needs to be quoted in `$1`; the space is used by the shell for wordsplitting before `$i`'s value is set.

Answer (score 0):

don't  $i

this will break by space

**using  "$i"**

Comment: It's too late to quote the variable after you try to iterate over the ouptut of `ls`.